# how do I create a jQuery nTier select compare script?

Tags: jquery, forms, compare, onselect

I am working with jQuery on trying to creating a match/mismatch alert.  Basically I have an nTier series of drop downs and input fields.

If a user drops down the select and chooses a value and that value matches another select group drop down. I then need to go and compare the price and perCase values and make sure there is a match.

If the prices don't match, I need to generate an alert...If the cases don't match I need to generate an alert.

I can do two, but I need this to aggregate and persist over an nTier amount of select/price/case groups and I am getting confused on how to do this.

Here is a cleaned up simplified form that I am working with.

```
<form name="form1" ID="form1">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <select name="selectA">
        <option id="A" value="">None</option>
        <option id="A" value="A">A</option>
        <option id="A" value="B">B</option>
        <option id="A" value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input id="priceA" type="text" name="price" value="8.99">
</td>
<td>
    <input id="perCaseA" type="text" name="perCase" value="4">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <select name="selectB">
        <option id="B" value="">None</option>
        <option id="B" value="A">A</option>
        <option id="B" value="B">B</option>
        <option id="B" value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input  id="priceB" type="text" name="price" value="8.99">
</td>
<td>
    <input  id="perCaseB" type="text" name="perCase" value="4">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sure this should be possible just using jQuery selectors, but not quite. Ah well. :)

This selects all of the `select` elements and then filters then by checking their values against the triggering `select` (apparently `xxx[value="xx"]` doesn't work for `select`). The `input` following any matching `select`s (the price textbox) is then filtered to make sure it doesn't have the same value as the triggering `select`'s following `input`. If you still get matches, you have an inconsistency and need an alert.

The rather ugly `parent().next().children()` is unfortunately needed because of the table.

You'll need an analogous bit of code for the per case, um, case. I don't think you can check both at once unfortunately.

```
$("select").change(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($("select").filter(function () { return $(this).val() == $this.val(); }).parent().next().children("input[value!='" + $this.parent().next().children("input").val() + "']").length != 0)
    {
        // alert
    }
});
```

Comment: Great; glad it helped you -- and hope the explanation made sense too. :)